# how do I store as a string a long quote (with weird characters)

Tags: string, r

For example, I would like to store the string below (including the endlines), but I cannot figure out what the function is. I thought `quote()` would work:

```
mystring <- quote(
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

%\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\stepcounter{figure}
)
```

but no luck.

Thank you, Xu.

Comment: Joshua is right. The quote function quotes expressions, not strings: `quote(1+x)` would return the expression `1+x` (and not complain that x is undefined). shQuote adds quotes to a string, but doesn't help you escape the backslashes...

Comment: Would `Sweave` be of any assistance by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
mystring <- "
\\documentclass{article}

\\usepackage{graphicx}

\\begin{document}

%\\tableofcontents
\\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\\listoffigures

\\newpage
\\stepcounter{figure}
"
cat(mystring)
#
# \documentclass{article}
#
# \usepackage{graphicx}
#
# \begin{document}
#
# %\tableofcontents
# \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
# \listoffigures
#
# \newpage
# \stepcounter{figure}
#

# assuming your string is stored in "foo.txt"
mystring <- paste(readLines("foo.txt"), collapse="\n")
```

Comment: thank you Joshua. Are you sure that there is no other way? In perl, for example, I think the "quote" function allows you to put in characters without needing to escape.

Comment: R doesn't have anything like Perl's "unevaluated" strings.  See `?Quotes`.

Comment: It seems strange that there is no other way. I guess my best option is to store my string in a file and read them with readLines. But then I would have to figure out how to insert a "\n" between each of the components of the vector.

Comment: You could do that and `readLines` will escape them for you (see my edit).

Comment: cool, thanks. I think that will be my best option. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The following reads it directly without paste: `readChar('c:/foo.txt', file.info('c:/foo.txt')$size)`